# Jinja2 Not working on Atom

Tags: python, html, atom-editor

```
import requests 
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():
    player_one = 'Anthony'
    return render_template('index.html', player_one = player_one)
```

My html code:

```
<div>
        <section class="section">
               <div class = "container">
                    <div class="tile is-parent is-4">
                      <article class="tile is-parent notification is-success">
                        <div align ="left">
                            <p class="title"> {{ player_one }}</p>
                        </div>
                      </article>

                    </div>
              </div>
        </section>
    </center>
```

It only displays `{{ player_one }}` instead of showing Anthony. I'm using Atom IDE, and I have the flask package installed on it, but passing the object from my index function seems to work

Comment: Try changing your import statements to: from flask import render_template, Flask

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Why do you need to import requests?

Comment: Aside from that, I tried out your example, it is working for me.

Comment: Oh lol I fixed by just running it as the Atom IDE administrator. Thank you for your input though guys, and sorry about wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by running Atom IDE as an administrator and downloaded atom-jinja2 from the packages